# BlackBerry in-app purchase similar to iPhone

Tags: blackberry

I want to implement in-app purchasing similar to what is available on the iPhone.
After searching, I learned that RIM will be releasing a BlackBerry Payment Service,
but I can't get any details about this.

Does anyone have details about how to implement in-app purchases on BlackBerry?

Answer (score 1):

RIM has a set of pages about [Application Platform Services](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/), one of which is the [Payment Service](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/platform/paymentservice.jsp), which includes a link to download the sdk. I haven't tried this personally.

Comment: I download Payment sdk and also i got sample code for it. Now i want to test this sample code on simulator locally. They specified app world 2.1 must be installed on device. Can i have to install it on simulator for local testing?